# Android one OnClick method for multiple buttons?

Tags: java, android, button, onclick

I started program little bit in android, 
I have 3 buttons in a single activity.

I saw some example codes that assign the same `OnClick` event to all the buttons (even if they perform completely different action) and in the method `Switch(id)` case case case...

What is the better approach? one `onClick` method and switching or a lot of methods, one for each button?

Thanks.

Comment: Use this answer for `view binding` https://stackoverflow.com/a/76097638/4833705

Answer (score 29, accepted):

If you want to reduce the coding lines then use `View's OnClick() with switch statement` and if you want to handle separately all click (for easily understanding and maintaining code) then use separate all `button's onClick().`

**Update:**

If you have declared Buttons in your Activity layout xml file, than write attribute `android:onClick=""` with same method name for all buttons and implement that method in your activity. Now you have one method for all buttons and in that method differentiate buttons with id.

**Example:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:orientation="vertical" >
    <Button android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:onClick="buttonOnClick"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Hello, I am a Button 1" />
    <Button android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:onClick="buttonOnClick"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Hello, I am a Button 2" />
    <Button android:id="@+id/button3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:onClick="buttonOnClick"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Hello, I am a Button 3" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Now in your Activity implement `buttonOnClick` like,

```
public void buttonOnClick(View view)
{
 switch(view.getId())
 {
  case R.id.button1:
  // Code for button 1 click
  break;

  case R.id.button2:
  // Code for button 2 click
  break;

  case R.id.button3:
  // Code for button 3 click
  break;
 }
}
```

Or you can apply same switch case for dynamically added buttons in your activity,
like instead of `buttonOnClick` you have to use **implemented View's OnClickListerner's** `onClick`.

Answer (score 35):

Use this way:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        button1.setOnClickListener(onClickListener);
        button2.setOnClickListener(onClickListener);
        button3.setOnClickListener(onClickListener);
}

private OnClickListener onClickListener = new OnClickListener() {
     @Override
     public void onClick(View v) {
         switch(v.getId()){
             case R.id.button1:
                  //DO something
             break;
             case R.id.button2:
                  //DO something
             break;
             case R.id.button3:
                  //DO something
             break;
         }

   }
};
```

Comment: That's abstract method. I think we don't need to care it.

Comment: How can we do that if we have the buttons in different activities?

Comment: @Subzero-273K, I don't think we can handle click event for buttons in different activity in a place. They should be handled in appropriate context.

Comment: id's in R.java file are not final . So can't be used in switch case.

Answer (score 6):

```
this.btnAddFriedtoFacebook = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.btnAddFriedtoFacebook);
this.btnAddFriedtoFacebook.setOnClickListener(this.backButtonClickListener);

public OnClickListener backButtonClickListener = new OnClickListener()
{
public void onClick(final View view)
{
   if (view == MatchInfoActivity.this.btnBack)
    {
        MatchInfoActivity.this.finish();
    }
    if( view == MatchInfoActivity.this.btnAddFried){
       Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
       MatchInfoActivity.this.startActivity(i);
    }
    if( view == MatchInfoActivity.this.btnAddBuddy){
       Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
       MatchInfoActivity.this.startActivity(i);
    }
}
};
```

Here is the good way.

Comment: He's not asking how to handle clicks, just which of two techniques he is already aware of is preferred.

Answer (score 2):

I think registering `onClick` in xml (layout) is better approach.

EDIT:

Found related threads :

1. [Best practice for defining button events in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6372104/best-practice-for-defining-button-events-in-android)
2. [best practices for handling UI events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5851418/best-practices-for-handling-ui-events)

Comment: I think it's a little weird to put it in the XML as it's the only UI behavior that works this way. Maybe if it were more like iOS where you set up all of your UI handlers from the UI designer it would make more sense.

Answer (score 0):

> Registered onClick event in the XML layout and then handle it in the code. This is how I would do it:

```
<Button
android:id="@+id/btplus"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="Click me"
android:onClick="onBtnClicked">
```

**Method in .class**

```
public void onBtnClicked(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.btplus:
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Plus is clicked" + "+", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 
            break;
        case R.id.btminu:
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Minus is clicked" + "-", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Little addition to @Nguyen answer.

```
findViewById(R.id.buttonOne).setOnClickListener(buttonClickListener);
....    ....    ....    ....
findViewById(R.id.buttonN).setOnClickListener(buttonClickListener);

private View.OnClickListener buttonClickListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.buttonOne:
                // do something
                break;
            ....    ....    ....    ....
            case R.id.buttonN:
                // do something
                break;
        }
    }
};
```

This could be useful, if you don't want to initialize the button variable, but want to track button click event. Thanks!