# OnClickListener is abstract, cannot be instantiated

Tags: java, android, sdk

I'm new to programming and have been racking my brain for the past couple of hours trying to resolve the issue. I know it's something stupid. I am trying to get each button to play a sound. Any help is greatly appreciated.
(ADDED `"import android.view.View.OnClickListener;"`, TURNED MY PROBLEMS GREEN UNTIL I CLOSED IT OUT WITH ";" BUT THEN THE IMPORT GRAYED OUT.)

```
public class PocketParent extends ActionBarActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        final MediaPlayer stopMP = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.btmg);
        final MediaPlayer dropMP = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.knock);
        final MediaPlayer popMP = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.oldsoulwr);
        final MediaPlayer noMP = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.smpr);
        final MediaPlayer yeahMP = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.upbeaty);

        ImageButton playstop = (ImageButton) this.findViewById(R.id.imageButton);
        ImageButton playdrop = (ImageButton) this.findViewById(R.id.imageButton2);
        ImageButton playpop = (ImageButton) this.findViewById(R.id.imageButton3);
        ImageButton playno = (ImageButton) this.findViewById(R.id.imageButton4);
        ImageButton playyeah = (ImageButton) this.findViewById(R.id.imageButton5);

        // (HERE IS WHERE MY PROBLEM LIES)
        // *OnClickListener is abstract, cannot be instantiated.*
        // (IT ALSO SAYS IT'S EXPECTING A "," OR " ' " RIGHT BEFORE "new",
        // but that doesn't work either.)

        playstop.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        playdrop.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        playpop.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        playno.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        playyeah.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()      {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                stopMP.start();
                dropMP.start();
                popMP.start();
                noMP.start();
                yeahMP.start();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        }
         ....
    }
}
```

Comment: It would be helpful for anyone ready to help to actually add a question.

Comment: Just have a look this [older discussion on Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25905086/multiple-buttons-onclicklistener-android).

Answer (score 3):

You just can't do this:

```
playstop.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
playdrop.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
playpop.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
....
```

because this means in java, you are passing to playstop method many arguments with no comma spliting,

It would make more sense syntaxically to do

```
playstop.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener());
playdrop.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener());
playpop.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener());
....
```

**But you can't do this either** because `View.OnClickListener` is an **interface** 
And creating an object of the `View.OnClickListener` just make no sense...

you need to instead implement anonymously that interface on all that buttons like you did it with the playYeah button

```
playyeah.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()      {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            .... 
        }
        });
 playstop.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()      {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            .... 
        }
        });
 playdrop.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()      {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            .... 
        }
        });
 Etc etc
```

Comment: That runs all the methods when any of the Views is clicked. That's not the intended behaviour (I assume).

Comment: You obviously dint get the idea in the answer.... I am focusing more on the fact that the interface must be implemented and not that every button must  execute the same code logic

Comment: Well anyway it's a much better answer now after your edits as it's even explaining what was wrong in the OP's logic in the first place.

Answer (score -2):

Try Change

```
ImageButton playstop = (ImageButton) this.findViewById(R.id.imageButton);
ImageButton playdrop = (ImageButton) this.findViewById(R.id.imageButton2);
ImageButton playpop = (ImageButton) this.findViewById(R.id.imageButton3);
ImageButton playno = (ImageButton) this.findViewById(R.id.imageButton4);
ImageButton playyeah = (ImageButton) this.findViewById(R.id.imageButton5);
```

to

```
ImageButton playstop = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton);
ImageButton playdrop = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton2);
ImageButton playpop = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton3);
ImageButton playno = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton4);
ImageButton playyeah = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton5);
```

Hope It help you!!