# opening buttons within the same main activity in android studio

Tags: android, button, tags, char, info

I want to be able to open 3 buttons within the same java class in Android studio , a map , button leading to text and pictures and the last one a video .. 
i used the following codes :

```
    public void location(View view) {

    Button great = (Button) findViewById(R.id.location);
    great.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),location`enter code here`.class);
     startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
}
```

the same for the other 2 buttons . as for the .xml file

```
   <Button
    android:layout_width="150dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/history"
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:onClick="location"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"/>
```

and the string is

```
<string name="map">Map</string>
<string name="location">Location</string>
<string name="info">information about related subject
</string>
```

the thing is how can i open all 3 buttons in the same main layout ? do i use

```
public void onClick(View view) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),location`enter code here`.class);
}
```

in all 3 buttons ? or do i have to assign each button to a different java class ? specially when all API setting (import google map ) shows up grey in the main java ?

Comment: Follow this question on stackoverflow: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25905086/multiple-buttons-onclicklistener-android

Comment: which attribute you think differentiate all your 3 button ? use that in Switch statment  .