# Android OnClickListener multiple views?

Tags: android, onclicklistener

`OnClickListener` best practices?

What is best practice if you have an `Activity` with, let's say 10 buttons, should you create the `OnClickListener` for each `View` (`Button`) or is it better to create a single `onClickListener` and just use a `switch` with the view ID to determine the clicked `View`?

Comment: You can assign the same click event handler to multiple Views in your layout. Then in the method, check **which** is the View that fired the event.

Comment: you can go with the second option (1 listener and switch)

Comment: instead of down vote guide other, if possible

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know that you know code therefore i can say only:

Switch is better as
a case or switch statement is considered easier to read and maintain

It is more manageable for having higher level of indentation than if.

Comment: This was probably the only answer that was to the point, I know the code and did not ask for examples but merely in practice what is the better choice. Thanks for some actual advice!

Comment: I am happy to help you. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
   switch (v.getId()) {
      case R.id.btn_1:
         //Logic_1
      break;
      case R.id.btn_2:
         //Logic_2
      break;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you search a little in Google or StackOverflow..

[Multiple Buttons `OnClickListener()` android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25905086/multiple-buttons-onclicklistener-android)

Best solution is switch:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

    switch (v.getId()) {

        case R.id.oneButton:
            // do your code
            break;

        case R.id.twoButton:
            // do your code
            break;

        case R.id.threeButton:
            // do your code
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use any thing which you like to use because as computational point both are same but if you want to sort your line of code then use signal with switch case

for references see this
[Multiple Buttons `OnClickListener()` android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25905086/multiple-buttons-onclicklistener-android)

Comment: they are not the same, each new click listener  is a new different inner class inside the activity

Comment: please see this http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/110106/what-is-the-proper-way-to-implement-the-onclicklistener-interface-for-many-butto

Comment: `as computational point both are same` and thats wrong