# How to perform onclick action on multiple buttons created dynamically in Android Studio

Tags: java, android

I am new to android and i want to create a workout application for my own use and for that my idea was-

1) The main activity will display an add button to add number of exercises. Lets suppose i need 5 exercises so 5 buttons will be create dynamically.

2) Now buttons are created what i need is when i click on any button the corresponding textToSpeech is called because this textToSpeech class will speak the name of exercise to be started. As each button is associated with a different exercise name and time.

**Activity images**-- [Main Activity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iqgCe.png) ,  [Add number of Buttons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ygh5Z.png)

I don't Know how to do this as there are lots of button and how to call different textToSpeech for each buttons.

Comment: [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25905086/multiple-buttons-onclicklistener-android) might help

Comment: But here we have fixed number of buttons in this answer(A calculator).

Comment: @Anu Generate Button id dynamically.

Comment: @Gowthaman M Ok.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just add onCLickListener in your activity

```
View.OnClickListener onClickListener=new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // put condition as per id of view
            }
        };
```

// here while creating dynamically add click listner

```
Button button=new Button(ButtonActivity.this);
        button.setText("Button"+i);
        button.setId(1000+i);
        button.setOnCLickListener(onClickListener);
```

I hope i gave you solution.

Answer (score 0):

Implement **OnClickListener()** on activity

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

    switch (v.getId()) {

        case R.id.oneButton:
            // do your code
            break;

        case R.id.twoButton:
            // do your code
            break;

        case R.id.threeButton:
            // do your code
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }

}
```

I hope this will help you,All the best.

Comment: I am dynamically assigning Id to button.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem in right manner you need to assign Ids to button while creating the buttons
start loop for five buttons

```
for(i=1;i<=5;i++){
   Button button=new Button(Activity.this);
   button.setId(R.id.existingButtonId+i);
   button.setWidth(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
   button.offsetTopAndBottom(40);
   button.setHint("hint x ");
   yourLayout.addView(button);
 }
```

after this implement onClickListener on your activity and use

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.ex1:
             //call textToSpeech for exercise one
            break;
        case R.id.ex2:
            //call textToSpeech for exercise two
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok. But how to arrange buttons like in the **Main Activity Image**

Comment: also set clickListner for button inside for loop  button.setOnClickListener(this);

Comment: String is not allowed in button.setId()

Comment: you can set the properties of button while creating them, I will update the answer to explain more

Comment: @Anu As String in not allowed what I will suggest is, use any existing Id along with loop count as ID for buttons, same thing shown in edited answer, hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Add clicklistener while inflating new button/view.

```
    private void addNewExcercise(String exercise) {

    Button button = new Button(ActivityMain.this);
    button.setText(exercise);

    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // do ur task here
        }
    });

    parentLinearLayout.addView(button);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

SecondActivity(Button display) No need to create Activity Create Java file and add the file in manifest

```
GridLayout gridLayout=new GridLayout(this);
    ViewGroup.LayoutParams layoutParams=new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(GridLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,GridLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    gridLayout.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
    gridLayout.setColumnCount(2);
    setContentView(gridLayout);
    if(getIntent()!=null){
        int buttoncount=getIntent().getIntExtra("value",0);
        for(int i=0;i<buttoncount;i++){
           Button button=new Button(ButtonActivity.this);
            button.setText("Button"+i);
            button.setId(1000+i);
            button.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.button_back);
            button.setPadding(10,10,10,10);
            gridLayout.addView(button);
        }
    }
```

Xml file  for background (create this file inside of drawable)

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="oval">
<solid android:color="#66ff0000" />
<size
    android:width="120dp"
    android:height="120dp"/>
</shape>
```

Any confusion then use this is full code of Java file

```
public class ButtonActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    GridLayout gridLayout=new GridLayout(this);
    ViewGroup.LayoutParams layoutParams=new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(GridLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,GridLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    gridLayout.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
    gridLayout.setColumnCount(2);
    setContentView(gridLayout);
    if(getIntent()!=null){
        int buttoncount=getIntent().getIntExtra("value",0);
        for(int i=0;i<buttoncount;i++){
           Button button=new Button(ButtonActivity.this);
            button.setText("Button"+i);
            button.setId(1000+i);
            button.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.button_back);
            button.setPadding(10,10,10,10);
            gridLayout.addView(button);
        }
    }

}
}
```

Manifest file

```
<activity android:name=".ButtonActivity"></activity>
```

and use the background file above...