# How to handle onClick for many buttons which do same actions?

Tags: java, android, onclicklistener

I have about 60 buttons and I want when click on any on them to do the same actions: get the text of the clicked button. check the text and if is correct disable it, otherwise display a toast.
I want to avoid to have a switch with 60 cases. Is there a shorter way to do it?

Comment: Duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25905086/multiple-buttons-onclicklistener-android

Comment: you can use Listview or recycle view to make 60 buttons.

Comment: Use recycler view to make 60 buttons

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `ButterKnife` and implememnt onclick as:

```
@OnClick({ R.id.button1, R.id.button, R.id.button})//as many you want
public void onButtonClick(Button button) {
  if (button.getText().equals("correctText")) {
    //Do whatever you want
  } else {
    Toast.makeText(this, "message", LENGTH_SHORT).show();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In layout xml add your onClick method name like this

```
 <Button    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:onClick="buttonOnClick"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

and in class file or Activity use like this

```
public void buttonOnClick(View view)
{
      //do your functionality here
}
```

Comment: and how to get the clicked button to set the actions?

Comment: buttonOnClick(View view) is for click event only