# Multiple AdListener in android kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, admob, ads, googleads-mobile-unity

I am making an app, for personal use, which has multiple banner ads on a single activity. I want to listen to `onAdLoaded()` events for all the ads. For this, I have to put `AdListener` for every ad. If I have ten ads, do I have to write the same code ten times?

So, my question is that is there any way to reduce this code like multiple buttons `onClickListener` like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25905086/multiple-buttons-onclicklistener-android)? 
I have already tried to do this in the same way as `onClickListener` of buttons, but it doesn't work.

**Some portion of my code:**

```
    ad1.adListener = object : AdListener() {
        override fun onAdLoaded() {
            super.onAdLoaded()
            incrementCounter()
        }
    }

    ad2.adListener = object : AdListener() {
        override fun onAdLoaded() {
            super.onAdLoaded()
            incrementCounter()
        }
    }

    ad3.adListener = object : AdListener() {
        override fun onAdLoaded() {
            super.onAdLoaded()
            incrementCounter()
        }
    }
```

I have to repeat the same code for all of my ad units.That's make my code bulky and it's my problem.

Comment: Can we have some code?

Comment: Yes off course. Look at edited question.@pablisco

Comment: I feel really split between 
- praising you for noticing code duplication 
and
- warning you could learn your lessons on basic Kotlin and program flow before better...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can group all your views in a list:

```
val adViews = listOf(ad1, ad2, ...)
```

And then, you can iterate over and set the listener:

```
adViews.forEach { 
  it.adListener = object : AdListener() {
    override fun onAdLoaded() {
      super.onAdLoaded()
      incrementCounter()
    }
  } 
}
```

Comment: This solved my problem but i have another problem. I'm loading 5 ads and refreshing it continuously. problem is ad stops refreshing automatically. did you have any solution for this??

Comment: Ask another question. However, this doesn't seem like a normal behaviour for ads. Google will probably ban your account if you try to do that.