# How to open a new activity on click of textview in android?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-studio, textview

I am new to android programming world, I have designed as a layout with username, password AS edittext control and "forgot password" as textview control, on click/tap of "forgot password", I want to open a new activity.

This is what I am trying, looking forward for your help.
My Application's xml and java code is mentioned below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_light">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtVwAccountLogin"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:text="Account Login"
            android:textColor="@android:color/background_light"
            android:textSize="24sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.057" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/eTxtUserName"
            android:layout_width="288dp"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            android:background="@android:color/background_light"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint=" Username"
            android:inputType="textPersonName"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.593"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.406" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/eTxtPassword"
            android:layout_width="290dp"
            android:layout_height="45dp"
            android:background="@android:color/background_light"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint=" Password"
            android:inputType="textPassword"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.606"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.535" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtVwForgetPassword"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Forget Password ?"
            android:textColor="@android:color/background_light"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.854"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.632" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnLogin"
            android:layout_width="128dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Login"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.779" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnRegister"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_light"
            android:text="Register"
            android:textColor="@android:color/background_light"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.15"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.662" />
    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

**Login.java**

```
    public class Login extends AppCompatActivity {
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.login);

            final TextView tvForgotPwd = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtVwForgetPassword);

            tvForgotPwd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    Toast.makeText(Login.this, "you clicked me", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(),PatientSearch.class);
                    startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
                }
            });
            final Button btnRegister = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnRegister);

            btnRegister.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(),MainActivity.class);
                    startActivityForResult(myIntent,0);
                }
            });
```

Comment: `I want to open a new activity.` we know that..but whats the issue in doing that?

Comment: What's the problem here ?

Comment: might consider watching this ans  : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25905086/multiple-buttons-onclicklistener-android

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Even though this question has been asked so many times, I decided to answer anyway. This will work:

```
tvForgotPwd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent myIntent = new Intent(Login.this, PatientSearch.class);
        startActivity(myIntent);
    }
});
```

Comment: Simple and Nice answer.

Answer (score -1):

In your onCreate() method, set an OnClickListener callback on your TextView. In the callback, use an Intent to start the desired activity.

Here is an exemple of code:

```
yourTextView= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtVwForgetPassword);

yourTextView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            intent.setData(Uri.parse("https://youraddress.com"));    
            startActivity(intent);
    }
});
```

Comment: where is `onClick`  attribute in `TextView` >

Comment: Indeed; I removed it since the onClick listener is set programmatically. No need for the downvote !

Answer (score -2):

Probably it is necessary to try a method

```
startActivity (new Intent (Activity.this, Open Activity.class));
```