# How do you check if the user has clicked some different buttons?

Tags: java, android

In a simple **app** I have some `buttons` (with `id.play_sound1 ... 15`), and I want to detect the user click random `buttons` for example **5 times**.

Can I do it in a simpler way than detect `onclick` on each `button`?

For example I want to display `toast` after user click random 5 `buttons`.

Comment: I never seen 15 play buttons, can i know why you need it. I think you can minify your code. Even there would be ways to handle onClick in short code. I want to know requirement, so i can tell you best.

Answer (score 0):

check this out

> https://stackoverflow.com/a/25905313/6998825

in your case  after check the ref

you can do this

```
int x = 0 ;
Override
public void onClick(View v) {

switch (v.getId()) {

 // increment x here or do whatever you want
    case R.id.oneButton:
        // do your code
        break;

    case R.id.twoButton:
        // do your code
        break;

    case R.id.threeButton:
        // do your code
        break;

    default:
        break;
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Place your `buttons` in `array`, generete **random number**, so that number would be an `button-array` index.