# Target any Button onClick, not a specific Button

Tags: android, kotlin

I have 4 buttons and want to have 1 `onClickListener` to detect which button was clicked (get the id of the button).

How can I achieve this?

`button1`
`button2`
`button3`
`button4`

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    }

}
```

I envision creating a `when` statement like so:

```
when (R.id) {
    R.id.button1 -> // do something
    R.id.button2 -> // do something
    R.id.button3 -> // do something
    R.id.button4 -> // do something
    else -> // do something
}
```

however I'm not sure how to target "any button clicked" and how the `onClickListener` would look in my Activity. Any idea?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Multiple Buttons' OnClickListener() android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25905086/multiple-buttons-onclicklistener-android)

Answer (score 0):

implement interface View.OnClickListener in MainActivity

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(), View.OnClickListener
```

and override onClick

```
    override fun onClick(p0: View?) {
        when (R.id) {
          R.id.button1 -> // do something
            R.id.button2 -> // do something
          R.id.button3 -> // do something
          R.id.button4 -> // do something
          else -> // do something
        }
    }
```

and put write

```
setOnClickListener(this)
```

Comment: Where do I put `setOnClickListener(this)`?

Comment: to the all button you want

Answer (score 0):

Do not implement multiple listeners, just implement the `View.OnClickListener` method like this:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {

}
```

Then add this:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
  // default method for handling onClick Events..
}
}
```

Define button listeners:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

setContentView(R.layout.your_layout);

Button one = (Button) findViewById(R.id.oneButton);
one.setOnClickListener(this); // calling onClick() method
Button two = (Button) findViewById(R.id.twoButton);
two.setOnClickListener(this);
Button three = (Button) findViewById(R.id.threeButton);
three.setOnClickListener(this);

}
```

Then get the Id and add click function:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

switch (v.getId()) {

    case R.id.oneButton:
        // do your code
        break;

    case R.id.twoButton:
        // do your code
        break;

    case R.id.threeButton:
        // do your code
        break;

    default:
        break;
}

}
```

This should work. Source:https://stackoverflow.com/a/25905313/9819031

But sorry that I don't know `Kotlin`

Comment: Please don't just copy another user's answer. If you believe another question already has the solution, then please flag this one as a duplicate.

Comment: @MikeM. Thanks for the suggestion sir!

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand you want to have default behavior on any button click and behaviors for each button click.

1. Implement `View.OnClickListener` to your `MainActivity`.

`class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(), View.OnClickListener {`

2. Implement `onClick(View)` method in your `MainAcitivity`.

In your `MainActivity`,

```
override fun onClick(v: View) {
    onAnyButtonClick()

    when(v.id) {
        R.id.button1 -> onButton1Click()
        R.id.button2 -> onButton2Click()
        R.id.button3 -> onButton3Click()
        R.id.button4 -> onButton4Click()
        else -> onOtherThanButtonClick()
    }
}
```

3. Attach `OnClickListener`s to your `Button`s.

In your `constructor` of `MainActivity`,

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    button1.setOnClickListener(this)
    button2.setOnClickListener(this)
    button3.setOnClickListener(this)
    button4.setOnClickListener(this)
}
```