# How can add same onClick for all imageView in Recyclerview?

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, onclicklistener

My project do bus ticket booking So, when click `item` in `recyclierview` that opens bus seat as 50 `imageView`. I know how can add `onClick` for one `imageView` but for 50 `imageView` that I don't know. I tried some solutions that I saw in stackOverflow. But nothing work. Could you give me advice or solution for making bus booking?

`public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {`

I tried add this code and implement `onClick` method but it don't do what is inside `onClick`.

I want add what `relative_bus_seat` `onClick` do to same for this 50 `imageView` do.

BusAdapter.java

```
 public class BusAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<BusAdapter.ViewHolder> {
        private Context context;
        private List<Bus> busList;
        private static String phoneNumber;
        private static final int PERMISSION_CODE = 101;
        private RecyclerView recyclerView;
        private Locale trlocale;


        VoyageAdapterToResultActivityListener voyageAdapterToResultActivityListener;

        public BusAdapter(Context _context, List<Bus> _busList, RecyclerView recyclerView) {
            this.context = _context;
            this.busList = _busList;
            this.recyclerView = recyclerView;
            this.trlocale = new Locale("tr-TR");
            voyageAdapterToResultActivityListener = (VoyageAdapterToResultActivityListener) context;
        }
        public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
            private TextView tvPrice, text_seat;
            private CardView cardV_row_voyage;
            private RelativeLayout relative_bus_seat;

            // Seats
            private ImageView imageV_seat1, imageV_seat2, imageV_seat3, imageV_seat4, imageV_seat5, imageV_seat6, imageV_seat7,
                    imageV_seat8, imageV_seat9, imageV_seat10, imageV_seat11, imageV_seat12, imageV_seat13, imageV_seat14, imageV_seat15,
                    imageV_seat16, imageV_seat17, imageV_seat18, imageV_seat19, imageV_seat20, imageV_seat21, imageV_seat22, imageV_seat23,
                    imageV_seat24, imageV_seat25, imageV_seat26, imageV_seat27, imageV_seat28, imageV_seat29, imageV_seat30, imageV_seat31,
                    imageV_seat32, imageV_seat33, imageV_seat34, imageV_seat35, imageV_seat36, imageV_seat37, imageV_seat38, imageV_seat39,
                    imageV_seat40, imageV_seat41, imageV_seat42, imageV_seat43, imageV_seat44, imageV_seat45, imageV_seat46, imageV_seat47,
                    imageV_seat48, imageV_seat49, imageV_seat50;

            private ViewHolder(View view) {
                super(view);
                recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
              // this.setIsRecyclable(false);
                constraintLayout_expanded = view.findViewById(R.id.constraintLayout2);
                cardV_row_voyage = view.findViewById(R.id.cardV_row_voyage);
                relative_bus_seat = view.findViewById(R.id.relative_seat);
               //  expandable_layout = view.findViewById(R.id.expandable_layout);
                progressB_dialog_seat = view.findViewById(R.id.progressB_dialog_seat);
                relativeL_row_voyage_view = view.findViewById(R.id.relativeL_row_voyage_view);
                relativeL_row_voyage_view_main = view.findViewById(R.id.relativeL_row_voyage_view_main);

                textView_seat2 = view.findViewById(R.id.textView_seat2);
                textView_seat5 = view.findViewById(R.id.textView_seat5);

                tvPrice = view.findViewById(R.id.tv_Price);
                textV_travel_duration_row_voyage = view.findViewById(R.id.textV_travel_duration_row_voyage);
                textV_from_time = view.findViewById(R.id.textV_from_time_row_voyage);
                imgLogo = view.findViewById(R.id.textV_company_name);
                textV_from_row_voyage = view.findViewById(R.id.textV_from_row_voyage);
                textV_to_row_voyage = view.findViewById(R.id.textV_to_row_voyage);
                text_seat = view.findViewById(R.id.text_seat);
                imageV_seat1 = view.findViewById(R.id.imageV_seat1);imageV_seat2 = view.findViewById(R.id.imageV_seat2);imageV_seat3 = view.findViewById(R.id.imageV_seat3);imageV_seat4 = view.findViewById(R.id.imageV_seat4);
                imageV_seat5 = view.findViewById(R.id.imageV_seat5);imageV_seat6 = view.findViewById(R.id.imageV_seat6);imageV_seat7 = view.findViewById(R.id.imageV_seat7);imageV_seat8 = view.findViewById(R.id.imageV_seat8);
                imageV_seat9 = view.findViewById(R.id.imageV_seat9);imageV_seat10 = view.findViewById(R.id.imageV_seat10);imageV_seat11 = view.findViewById(R.id.imageV_seat11);imageV_seat12 = view.findViewById(R.id.imageV_seat12);
                imageV_seat13 = view.findViewById(R.id.imageV_seat13);imageV_seat14 = view.findViewById(R.id.imageV_seat14);imageV_seat15 = view.findViewById(R.id.imageV_seat15);imageV_seat16 = view.findViewById(R.id.imageV_seat16);
                imageV_seat17 = view.findViewById(R.id.imageV_seat17);imageV_seat18 = view.findViewById(R.id.imageV_seat18);imageV_seat19 = view.findViewById(R.id.imageV_seat19);imageV_seat20 = view.findViewById(R.id.imageV_seat20);
                imageV_seat21 = view.findViewById(R.id.imageV_seat21);imageV_seat22 = view.findViewById(R.id.imageV_seat22);imageV_seat23 = view.findViewById(R.id.imageV_seat23);imageV_seat24 = view.findViewById(R.id.imageV_seat24);
                imageV_seat25 = view.findViewById(R.id.imageV_seat25);imageV_seat26 = view.findViewById(R.id.imageV_seat26);imageV_seat27 = view.findViewById(R.id.imageV_seat27);imageV_seat28 = view.findViewById(R.id.imageV_seat28);
                imageV_seat29 = view.findViewById(R.id.imageV_seat29);imageV_seat30 = view.findViewById(R.id.imageV_seat30);imageV_seat31 = view.findViewById(R.id.imageV_seat31);imageV_seat32 = view.findViewById(R.id.imageV_seat32);
                imageV_seat33 = view.findViewById(R.id.imageV_seat33);imageV_seat34 = view.findViewById(R.id.imageV_seat34);imageV_seat35 = view.findViewById(R.id.imageV_seat35);imageV_seat36 = view.findViewById(R.id.imageV_seat36);
                imageV_seat37 = view.findViewById(R.id.imageV_seat37);imageV_seat38 = view.findViewById(R.id.imageV_seat38);imageV_seat39 = view.findViewById(R.id.imageV_seat39);imageV_seat40 = view.findViewById(R.id.imageV_seat40);
                imageV_seat41 = view.findViewById(R.id.imageV_seat41);imageV_seat42 = view.findViewById(R.id.imageV_seat42);imageV_seat43 = view.findViewById(R.id.imageV_seat43);imageV_seat44 = view.findViewById(R.id.imageV_seat44);
                imageV_seat45 = view.findViewById(R.id.imageV_seat45);imageV_seat46 = view.findViewById(R.id.imageV_seat46);imageV_seat47 = view.findViewById(R.id.imageV_seat47);imageV_seat48 = view.findViewById(R.id.imageV_seat48);
                imageV_seat49 = view.findViewById(R.id.imageV_seat49);imageV_seat50 = view.findViewById(R.id.imageV_seat50);



            relative_bus_seat.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        final int position = getAdapterPosition();
                        final Bus bus = busList.get(position);

                        final CartStateResultBus resultBus1 = Cart.getInstance(context).ifValidAddToCartBus(bus);
                        ////aynı şeye iki kere tıklanırsa
                        if (resultBus1.isSuccessBus) {
                            ////carttan siler aynı directionları ve yayın yapar result activitye
                            Cart.getInstance().addBusToCart(bus);
                            notifyDataSetChanged();
                            voyageAdapterToResultActivityListener.updateAdded();



                        } else  {                           Cart.getInstance(context).removeFromCartByDirectionBetweenSameTypesBus(bus.getDirection());
                            notifyDataSetChanged();
                            voyageAdapterToResultActivityListener.updateRemoved();

                        }

                    }
                });
            }


        }
        @Override
        public int getItemCount() {
            return busList.size();
        }



}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly implement the interface **OnClickListener** to your `ViewHolder`

```
 public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener
```

Then add the click listeners to image view like this

```
private ViewHolder(View view) {
                super(view);

      //Your code here after

 imageV_seat1.setOnClickListener(this);
    //add for all the image views


}
```

And on Override method `onClick` user Switch statement to get the fast execution

```
public void onClick(View v) {

        switch (v.getId()) {

            case R.id.imageV_seat1:

               // Code Here
                break;

     // add for reset ids

}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To make code small make use of `lambda`:

```
holder.yourImage.setOnClickListener(view -> {
    // do something here
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can implement onCLickListener and in onClick() method check its imageView, If its imageView you can write your logic.

```
 public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener

@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    if(view instanceof ImageView)
   //write your logic here or you can get view.getId method also to write logic for individual imageview
}
```

Comment: I tried in debug but It don't step onClick. So, it don't work.

Comment: in this please bind your imageview like, imageview.setOnClickListeners(this);

Answer (score 1):

This can be implemented using some logical game. Though I have not tested it as I do not have IDE available now but the code should work.

```
    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener { 
    private Button mButton; 

     private ViewHolder(View view)
    { 
        .....Your existing code

        button1.setOnClickListener(this); 
        button2.setOnClickListener(this);
        button3.setOnClickListener(this);
        .
        .
        .
        button50.setOnClickListener(this);
    } 

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) 
    { 
        switch (view.getId()) { 
        case R.id.button1: 
        case R.id.button2:
        case R.id.button3:
        .
        .
        .
        case R.id.button50:
            // Do something... by doing this all case will come to this block to execute.
            // Remember, do not use break in any of the above case.
        } 
    } 
}
```

Let me know if it solved your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Just do like that:-

```
holder.yourImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // your code hare
            }
        });
```

Comment: I know this but I don't want add same long code for all imageView. That's not logical. 50 imageView it's lots of code.

Comment: first of all, you don't need to create so many images like this. Recycler view can create you all the views and after that, you can set onClick on your holder.itemView and get the position then do what you want to do.