# how to provide single clicklistener for two items in ConstraintLayout?

Tags: android-constraintlayout

I was able to achieve same using other layout (e.g. LinearLayout) by adding clickListener to child LinearLayout.

```
    <LinearLayout>
       <LinearLayout>
         <ImageView>
         <TextView>
      </LinearLayout>
      <LinearLayout>
         <ImageView>
         <TextView>
      </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
```

How to achieve same using ConstraintLayout? Is there any way to avoid nesting w less performance overhead?

Comment: Maybe [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25905086/multiple-buttons-onclicklistener-android) can help

Comment: @TamirAbutbul I'm looking more from user's point of view, where click for ImageView or TextView have same click ripple effect. Both should look as if single component.