# Android: code refactoring advice

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I am creating a todo list kind of app. This is an app with 7 screens to set target and complete that. A screenshot [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SsNwD.jpg) . Now while coding I realized there is lots of redundancy in the code, like:

1> For 7 day of week i need to create 7 fragments then for all the 7 fragments i need to perform exactly same operations. Can I do this w/o 7 fragments?

2> There are 15 checkboxes and 15 textview now for all-i need to get a reference, then perform onclick operations separately on each one and settext and gettext on each as user try to modify them.

here is one of the textview modify code:

```
 ptext2 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.p_textview2);
        ptext2.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onLongClick(View view) {
                AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
                alertDialog.setTitle("Target");
                alertDialog.setMessage("Set your target");
                final EditText input = new EditText(getActivity());
                alertDialog.setView(input);
                alertDialog.setPositiveButton("Set", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                        String targetInp = input.getText().toString();
                        ptext2.setText(targetInp);
                        p2 = ptext2.getText().toString();
                        addEventsToDB();
                    }
                });
                alertDialog.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                    }
                });
                alertDialog.show();
                return true;
            }
        });
```

similarly there are 15 more for textview and then checkbox an I need to do this for all the 7 fragments.
[Here is my full code of one of the fragment](http://ideone.com/3HyvjI)

Since this kind of apps are the first app for most of the users learning android development what should be done to improve this code?

EDIT:
For Multiple buttons onclick listener's I am creating an inner class and then using switch for button specific operations.

```
switch(view.getId()){
    case R.id.id1:
        //do something
        break;
.....
}
```

From [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7873480/android-one-onclick-method-for-multiple-buttons). Now I only need to figure out what to do about 7 fragments (Can it be done with just one fragment?)

Comment: Is there sth in my answer that you cannot understand? It would solve your problem.

Comment: I propose to create another more specific question about fragments with a piece of code. It's hard to guess what are you talking about and it's becoming a bit messy here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about naming your implementation of `View.OnLongClickListener` class like:

```
class OnDayClickListener extends View.OnLongClickListener {

    @Override
    public boolean onLongClick(final View view) {
        // here use view instead of ptext2
    }
}
```

then use

```
ptext2.setOnLongClickListener(new OnDayClickListener());
// this repeats for every textbox
```

Comment: Thanks, it will improve my code.
Can you advice mre for this for 7 day of week i am creating 7 fragments then for all the 7 fragments i am performing exactly same operations. Can I do this w/o 7 fragments?

Comment: What do you mean by performing exactly the same operations? I'm not Android developer so I can't advice with fragments particulary. But similar trick can be used with Fragment component probably too.

Comment: ptext2.setText(targetInp);
 p2 = ptext2.getText().toString();

How to write a generalized implementation of this for each textview?

Comment: onLongClick(final View view) - view is the actual object that has been clicked. For every object (TextView) that you attach Listener of this class, view will be this clicked object - exactly the one that you need.

Comment: but vies.setText("") and views.getText() is giving error with views.

Comment: If you describe an error maybe I could guess why it occurs.

Comment: "Error:(381, 25) error: cannot find symbol method setText()"
I think setText() and getText() are not the view class methods. TextView class extends view. I don't know how to resolve this

Comment: Not I got it. I can get the textview using switch(view.getId()){case ...} a do button specific operations in cases. Got help from this SO ansewer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7873480/android-one-onclick-method-for-multiple-buttons

Comment: If you are sure that your View is always TextView (it is in your case) you can cast it like `final TextView textView = (TextView) view;` inside. Then you can call both methods on `textView`.